# How to cache contents of iframe which is loaded in Angular PWA?

Tags: angular, caching, iframe, progressive-web-apps

I've created an **Angular PWA** which basically contains the **iframe**(Which loads the content from other domain). It works fine, But I am unable to cache the contents of iframe to load the PWA in offline mode.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? I'm also in need for this

Comment: @none, I've figured it out. We can retrieve the contents of iframe by using ContentWindow & cache it

Comment: @vinaynvd can you share the code?